# Assign contents of file to variable over remote ssh from a script running in Jenkins

Tags: linux, ssh, jenkins, cat, assign

I have opened a remote ssh session from a script and on remote server there is a file containing version information. 
I am trying to assign that version to variable and move current version contents to folder name same as version.

The main script is running in jenkins

I am doing something like this

```
ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa -t -t remoteServer<<EOF
cd $WEB_DIR
VERSION=$(cat $WEB_DIR/version.info)
mv -f $WEB_DIR $BACKUP_DIR/$VERSION
exit
EOF
```

My VERSION variable is always empty. When I run same locally on that server it gives me version value. Something is different over remote ssh session within a script

Comment: Where is WEB_DIR set? See [this](http://superuser.com/questions/800736/how-to-print-index-in-a-for-loop-being-executed-in-remote-host-through-ssh/800739#800739).

Comment: Thank you @Kenster, I used something similar from manuals.

Answer (score 3):

Actually I found the way to do it in 2 steps.

$WEB_DIR is set as local variable set in main script.

```
$WEB_DIR="/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT"

OLD_VERSION=$(ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa -tt user@remoteServer "cat $WEB_DIR/version.info")

ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa -t -t user@remoteServer<<EOF
cd $WEB_DIR
mv -f $WEB_DIR $BACKUP_DIR/$OLD_VERSION
# I am executing more commands in here
exit
EOF
```

Use of double quotes "" in first command is must if want to use local variable.